# SPF, SRS and aliases on Gmail and other external services

Tags: postfix, spf

A lot of my mailservers users are using Gmail to send with an address on my domain as their alias. In an attempt to combat e-mail forgery I have implemented an SPF record and have been advised to change the `~all` to `-all`

Is SRS helpful in this situation, or do I 'just' need to inform all of my users to stop using aliases on Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail uses it's own method of authorizing users to send on behalf of other domains, thus SPF isn't applied as the emails are FROM gmail.

However, if the emails are FROM your domain and -all does not suffice, I would recommend adding a DMARC policy, I would use either dmarcian or postmark to get started, once you have established that your SPF is accurate you can switch to a reject policy.  I have found better acceptance of DMARC over simply using DKIM or SPF alone.  If you want forwarders to survive, you'll need to add DKIM to those emails going out.  If SPF and DKIM fail in relax mode, the DMARC policy is applied, if either one passed, the message passes.  You can additionally make SPF or DKIM required.

Good Luck!